# What is the best way to create objects in Django on server startup?

Tags: python, django

Essentially, I am creating an application where users can have multiple skills. So I have it setup like this:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Listing(models.Model):
  ...(other stuff for the model here)
  skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill,)
```

And then I'm going to create a form that looks something like this:

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
  skill = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Skill.objects.all())
  class Meta:
    model = Listing
```

The end result being that I want each skill to show up as a checkbox in the form. So there might be 30 skills to choose from, and then the user could just check any of them that they were proficient in. The problem I am facing is that I somehow have to create those 30 skill objects initially. I know how to create objects, but I don't know where to put the code so that the ~30 skills only get created the first time the server starts. Where should I create the initial skill objects? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you not got a database you can put your `Skill`s in? Surely the way forward would be to store your `Skill`s in a table and query them from there.

Comment: There is a database, but I would prefer to use Python/Django to do this because I don't have much experience dealing directly with SQL and I delete the database often since I am still developing the application and constantly changing the models.

Comment: You should you use a database and South http://south.aeracode.org/ for dealing with models "constantly changing". Or use Django 1.7!

Comment: I don't really want to migrate anything other than the Skill objects. Is there no place I can put a script in Django that only runs when the db is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a fixtures.json file and use loaddata:

**fixtures.json**

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "appname.skill",
        "fields": {
            "name": "skill name",
        }
    }
}
```

cmd line:

```
python manage.py loaddata path/to/fixtures.json
```

Here are some docs for it: [Providing initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)